# Perfect infinitive- Expressing future

Tags: grammaticality

The perfect infinitive can refer to something that will be completed at a point in the future.

Example:

> We hope to have finished the building works by the end of March.

Can I replace the verb "hope" with "be"?

We are to have finished the building works by the end of March.

Comment: Why not just “We hope/are to finish . . . by the end of March?  Hope and are are different.

Comment: @Xanne Because "We are to finish" expresses one's own expectation, but "We are to have finished" expresses the expectations of others.

Comment: You're not "replacing _hope_ with _be_" (and by extension, leaving everything else "the same"). In fact, you're forming a different construction, with a different meaning, and different grammar, that uses _be_.